# Error "scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found" when compiling Play framework tests

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I'm getting this error when executing "play clean test" for every play project on my system:

```
[info] Compiling 9 Scala sources and 302 Java sources to $HOME/Workspace/sis/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
[error] error while loading , error in opening zip file
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:48)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:61)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getPackage(Mirrors.scala:172)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredPackage(Mirrors.scala:175)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:181)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage(Definitions.scala:181)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:182)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass(Definitions.scala:182)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:997)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr(Definitions.scala:996)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1126)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses(Definitions.scala:1125)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1169)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1169)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1234)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.(Global.scala:1281)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:87)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:72)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:73)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:35)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:29)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:101)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:70)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:88)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:60)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:24)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:22)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.cycle(Incremental.scala:45)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:29)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:20)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:96)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:44)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:31)
    at sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:79)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:572)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:572)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf2$1.apply(Structure.scala:578)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf2$1.apply(Structure.scala:578)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
[error] (test:compile) scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
[error] Total time: 39 s, completed Apr 1, 2014 4:08:27 PM
play clean test  103.37s user 3.60s system 224% cpu 47.737 total
```

This has suddenly started happening recently after updating some packages with homebrew, though I'm not sure that's the cause as I uninstalled homewbrew and went to using the play zip packages from their website only to get the same problem.

Other things I've tried:

- Clearing out .sbt, .ivy, .m2 directories in home
- Uninstalling/reinstalling scala/play/java, using the play framework clean commands, cleaning out the repo etc.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR The powermock.jar file we were depending on was not a jar file.

I was able to run "play test" in a fresh play project, but none of the more mature projects in my system. So I decided to remove files until I had passing tests. I first deleted all the scala tests (we have a mix of Java and Scala) and got this far more informative error:

```
[error] error: error reading /usr/local/Cellar/play/2.1.1/libexec/repository/cache/org.powermock/powermock-mockito-release-full/jars/powermock-mockito-release-full-1.5.jar; cannot read zip file
```

I had a look at the jar file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body, #partner, iframe {
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                border:0;
                outline:0;
                font-size:100%;
                vertical-align:baseline;
                background:transparent;
            }
            body {
                overflow:hidden;
            }
        </style>
        <meta content="NOW" name="expires">
        <meta content="index, follow, all" name="GOOGLEBOT">
        <meta content="index, follow, all" name="robots">
        <!-- Following Meta-Tag fixes scaling-issues on mobile devices -->
        <meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" name="viewport">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="partner"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write(
                    '<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"'
                            + 'src="//sedoparking.com/frmpark/'
                            + window.location.host + '/'
                            + 'tierraexpired'
                            + '/park.js">'
                    + '<\/script>'
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

We had a dependency on powermock 1.5:

```
"org.powermock" % "powermock-mockito-release-full" % "1.5" % "test"
```

Taking a quick look at the powermock site it seemed that powermock 1.5 was deprecated and perhaps it had been pulled. But we're actually serving this particular file from Artifactory and for whatever reason it's started serving up HTML instead.

Not sure why it didn't fail signature verification or give us a slightly more informative error.